# np.nanstd return inf value in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to calculate the standard deviation of `np.array` using `np.nanstd` but it returns `inf` instead of actual value.
my numpy array looks

```
[[1.19665046e-311 1.19665144e-311 nan ... 2.29685654e+049 4.98919540e+228]
 [2.00798195e+165  8.02088921e+035 ... nan nan 1.10386271e+031]
..]
```

And the value that return it after computing np.nanstd is

```
[inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf 
inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf
 inf inf inf inf]
```

Why it gives `inf` value and how can I get actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just at a glance, some values inside your array are too large. Take `4.98919540e+228` for example. Standard deviation is calculated by `root(sum(square(x-x_mean))/N)`, so you're computing e+228 square, which is e+456 - more than what python can handle. It'll keep showing `inf` unless you put smaller values, like below e+150.